# Can we force rendering a text as binary when 'to_yaml'?

Tags: ruby, binary, yaml

```
requrie 'yaml'
hash = {:title=>'abc'}
hash.to_yaml
```

will output:

```
--- 
title: abc
```

Is there any method to force the title to be a binary, like:

```
---
title: !binary|
  5Lit5pa
```

**UPDATE**

I'm asking this because I want to dump the data from database to yml files. But the text in the database, contains English and non-English text, and both may have such code:

```
<% xxx %>
```

When I use `rake db:fixtures:load`, there will be an error like `method xxx not found`.

I can replace '<%' with '<%%' before writing to file, but it's only works for the English text -- If there is any non-English charactors, the content will be binary. When loading back, '<%%' is still '<%%'. I don't find a good solution unless I can force 'to_yaml' always using 'binary' for text.

Comment: Just a short note: You are throwing away the nice fact that YAML already defines which character encoding to use when storing text as binary. This makes interoperability much harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is 'no'.

The long is - override an `String#to_yaml` (or `Object#to_yaml`) method with your custom implementation.